# How to write hex 0x12 in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I need pass a hex parameter values 0x12 into a function, but when I type &H0x12, it gave me error. How can I write this value? Thank you very much.

Comment: Learn to answer a question properly please you need to show research you have already tried, also your code that you already have written to try.

Comment: `&H12`  Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  Hex notation is amply covered and easily googled

Comment: @Plutonix thanks, I did research, but I didn't find the answer.

Comment: Google your title and examine the third hit [Using Hexadecimal values in VB.NET](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/290ca84a-fdea-4d02-99bf-b534e91cea5d/using-hexadecimal-values-in-vbnet?forum=netfxcompact).  Then read [ask] and take the [tour], please

Comment: Plutonix , Danny James, thanks guys, my fault. next time I will research more and carefully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is not quite right.

```
0x12
```

in VB would be:

```
&H12
```